# Layout help: zIndex and Overflow

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout, antd

I have a fixed header and sidebar. Ideally, I want the content to stay within the fixed layout. My current issue is that all my content is held within `<Content>` and when I scroll down I want to always have a gap between the content and the header.

[image: Edit condescending-hoover-uyktt]

**Goal space between header and content when scrolling down**

[image]

**Currently, there is no space.**

[image]

Comment: If you don’t want to put the scrollbar onto the content element itself, but keep it as a full-page scrollbar, then I think you have no other option than to emulate this “gap” by adding a border or padding to your header, or positioning another element above this location so that it “blacks out” the content under it. (That will of course probably not work smoothly for elaborate backgrounds using images etc., but mostly for solid colors.)

Comment: Thanks for that. What would you suggest I should do for the "best practice" approach? Ideally, I want to have a full-page layout and scroll only within the content component.

Comment: @04FS Sorry, I forgot to add the Codesandbox link. Please see my current setup. Background colors have been changed for components to be seen easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make body tag unscrollable and add 2 divs in it. one is the simple div with height that you want to kept between fixed header and content, and second one is the div with content class and put content in it. After that you can add overflow scroll on div what "content" class
[Here is the link of example](https://codepen.io/huseyn0w/pen/JjjWJwX)

```
body{
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:100px 0 0 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.fixed-header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color:#000;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.spacer{
  height: 50px;

}

.content{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:60vh;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to emulate this by having a <div className="container><div className="wrapper"></div></div> but cant seem to get it to work. Are you able to make the changes on the codesandbox to visually see this?